# REGEX in mysql table containing html data

Tags: html, mysql, regex

I have a table that stores html templates in a mysql database. Now I have to perform some text replacement on them. However my target text is also present in some of the anchor tags and I don't want that to be replaced.

EX :

`<body> ... (has huge html crap)... ...<a href="www.whatever.com/abc-KEYWORD-xyz/qwerty"></a>......(Some more html crap) <a href="www.google.com"></a> ... (a bit more of html crap) ... </body>`

Task is to replace the occurrences of the "KEYWORD" with "NEW KEYWORD" in the body but not the urls.

It would also be helpful if I can first find such cases where the KEYWORD is a part of a link in a given template.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is not capable of such advanced string manipulation.

However, if you were to have a one-time-use PHP script do the editing (ie. select from the table, for each row process and update), you can do this:

```
// foreach row as $row
$newtext = preg_replace("(<a\b.*?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|KEYWORD)","NEW KEYWORD",$row['data']);
```

What this does is look for links (very approximate Regex but should suffice in almost all cases here), then skip over them. Then, it looks for `KEYWORD` and replaces it with `NEW KEYWORD`.

You can use this to quickly and easily handle the replacement.

If that "almost all cases" thing above turns out to not be enough, you can use `DOMDocument` to load the HTML into a parser and process text nodes only from there.

Comment: I do have a ruby script to do it. Wanted to do it on Mysql. Constraints :) Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find  the cases where the KEYWORD is a part of a link with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE html REGEXP '<a[^>]*KEYWORD';
```

Comment: Gives the cases, still looking for a method to replace everything but this.

Comment: any suggestions about cherry picking the NON LINK occurrences ?